# Unknown: Failed to write session data (user). Please verify that the current setting of session.save_path is correct (/tmp) in Unknown on line 0

Tags: php, session, nginx, vps

I have spent several hours searching and attempting things but nothing seems to make a difference.

We have a VPS running nginx + php-fpm that only has one Joomla! website and also a subdirectory for iDevAffiliate.

Everything was working fine until I did a yum update - updated everything that was due and then updated iDevAffiliate from 7.4 to 8. Now I'm not sure which action is the culprit but at this point on iDevAffiliate is not working - but they say it's server related.

Users are able to login and use a fairly big Joomla! website without any problems - this makes me doubt the server is really at fault.

When attempting to login to the front-end or admin page of iDevAffiliate - this error at the bottom of the page

> Warning: Unknown: Failed to write session data (user). Please verify that the current setting of session.save_path is correct (/tmp) in Unknown on line 0

- Rebooted the server a few times as that's suppose to clean
  the directory.
- Manually tried clearing the directory (wasn't many files
  since the reboot).
- Confirmed and tried re-applying CHMOD 1777 (was already set) -  also tried CHMOD u+w
- Confirmed session.save_path in php config is set to "/tmp" (no trailing spaces)
- /tmp is running off / when I checked with "df -k /tmp"

What am I missing? I find it really odd that only iDevAffiliate is causing problems, coincidentally right after I upgraded it.

You help would be much appreciated.

Edit: Here's some DF info I've been asked about. https://i.stack.imgur.com/3gWUL.jpg

Answer (score -1, accepted):

We found the problem was actually with a bug in suhosin and have resolved it by disabling suhosin. What a weird one.

Apparently, suhosin isn't fully supported for php 5.4

Comment: i have same problem in my PHP project. how do you solve it?